# Compiz effects not working on an Asus 1215B with FGLRX

Tags: compiz

The title says it all.

ASUS 1215B, Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit up-to-date and proprietary FGLRX drivers activated. I followed some instructions given by an ubuntu user and managed to enable some features (like woobly windows), but compiz effects are still not working.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found a quick solution to enable compiz effects on my ASUS 1215B:

• Go to Applications > System Tools > CompizConfig Settings Manager > Effects;

• Click on Animations;

• Click on ">" until you find the "Effect Settings" tab;

• Enable (tick) "Random Animations For All Events".

Good luck!